# svn terminal: how to copy out files new or modified in one svn project One Time

Tags: macos, file, svn, terminal, copy

MAC OSX TERMINAL, svn-version 1.6.18:
I need to copy files which are new created or modified at one time in svn project.
There are many files ,so that If I copy them one by one,it will take almost an hour and it will drive me crazy.
Does there have any SVN command can do this
OR svn app in mac osx?

files like this:
    localhost:xxx kuma$ svn status
    M       navobj.js
    ?       impl/sys_eventlog_impl.js
    ?       impl/serviceManagement_imp.js
    ?       impl/checkRole.js
    M       impl/partition_create_impl.js
    M       impl/configure_user_imp.js

Comment: `svn co your-svn-repository`

Comment: I have co it in my computer.I modified some files and create some .I wanna copy files which are new created or modified  in the project to another folder.

Comment: Is this (extended) definition of your task "I have repository with X commits in it and want to get all files, affected in revision-range N:M" correct? Because "new or modified in project" is too wide and common specification

Comment: files like this in terminal after use svn status:

M       navobj.js
?       impl/sys_eventlog_impl.js
?       impl/serviceManagement_imp.js
?       impl/checkRole.js
M       impl/partition_create_impl.js
M       impl/configure_user_imp.js